# how to set icon in center of button in xml

Tags: android, icons

i have a button that have a background
i want to set icon for button in center position
this is my xml code

```
        <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/imgbutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
```

but icon appear in left of button
please help

its possible to set icon in shape to use for multiple button?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use icon only (without text) so you should go with `ImageButton`

Comment: i want first have a icon and when click the icon replace with text

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Extend Button class and provide custom handling in your overridden class, then use it in XML
2. Use a RelativeLayout and then put all your content inside it and toggle visibility of what they should see. Add click handler
3. Use Binding on layout for visibility handling
4. Use custom selector where you swap out the center content for drawable or other behaviors as they interact with the button.

Choose your poison, but there are dozens of ways to skin that cat.
Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

> i want first have a icon and when click the icon replace with text

Make the icon an imageButton, and my text a TextView. Set them at their degsinated locations. Set text's view opacity to be 0 (aka transparent). And as set an onclick listener on the icon to change the opacity of the text view to be 1,  and the icon to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageButton` and set src image

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView or ImageButton control instead of button. if you want to show only icon or image.

For your requirement, use textview and imageview and set visibility as per your requirement. when you want to show image set visibility -> visible to imageview and set visibility -> gone to textview. and same vice versa.